# trying to switch these staements from pdo to mysqli

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

How can I change the following piece of code

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=XXXXXX;dbname=XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX');
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

and this piece of code

```
try
{
    $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM demo_table ORDER BY id', $options);
}
catch(paginationException $e)
{
    echo $e;
    exit();
}
```

from pdo to mysqli so that they correspond with each other?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what difference the database makes to the pagination code block, based off of what you've provided. Have you done any research on mysqli? Its fairly straightforward.

At any rate, this code replaces your PDO code. Your pagination code block requires more details before that can be addressed.

```
 try
    {
            $dbh = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            echo "Error: " $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I have done a lot of research. Seems silly to use pdo when all i am using is php and mysql. I don't need 12 drivers and php doesn't even support named parameters. Mysqli makes more sense for my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. If you would mind accepting this as the answer (by hitting the checkmark under the up/down arrows) I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Actually... PDO has a much better interface and is therefore much easier to work with than MySQLi... The fact that it is arguably DB agnostic is really just a bonus.